# HTML from DAM delivered with MIME type application/save

Tags: aem

I have some raw HTML files in DAM standard on AEM v5.6.1 that I've activated. In the DAM asset view, it's indicating "text/html" as the asset type. When I visit the URL of the activated asset, the http response delivers content-type application/save.

text/html is defined as a mime type in the Sling Mime type service.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The html in /content/dam was still causing a download on the Publish instance for me.

In the end I found the following Osgi config did the trick:

**Dam Safe Binary Filter** (com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.DamContentDispositionFilter), remove text/html from Blacklisted Mime Types

Answer (score 1):

This is doable but you can't store the HTML as a dam:Asset.  It needs to be an nt:file, as if it were an image that was part of a clientlib under /etc

I haven't investigated whether or not turning off asset creation for that type is possible, but I can verify that this method works and that the files are viewable in the DAM manager.

Comment: Thank you.  I've now seen that the assets are delivered with the expected MIME types when replicated to the publish instance; it's only the author instance exhibiting the behavior.